# como ajustar mi cabecera de mi tabla a la de mi tbody de mi tabla?

Tags: php, javascript, html

[image: La Cabecera de mi tabla esta el mismo tamaño que mi tbody]

Lo que quiere quiero lograr es que mi thead sea el mismo tamaño que mi tbody

> Enla parte superior puse position:fixed par que mi cabecera sea estatica pero  el problem es que ahora no se ajusta el tamaño de mi tbody sinos toma su propio tamaño
>
> En el tbody estoy cargando datos desde una base de datos

```html
 <div class="table-responsive-xl " style="width:100%;overflow:auto; max-height:500px;">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped egt">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="position:fixed;background:#FFF;">
                        <th >Nombre</th>
                        <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                        <th>Apellido Materno</th>
                        <th>DNI</th>
                        <th>Lugar</th>
                        <th>Fecha Nacimiento</th>
                        <th>Direccion</th>
                        <th>Telefono</th>
                        <th>Celular</th>
                        <th>Foto</th>
                        <th>E-mail</th>
                        <th>Genero</th>
                        <th>MODIFICAR</th>
                        <th>ELIMINAR</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody></tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: Creo que te hace falta una mejor formulación de tu pregunta, no vemos nada de código en texto, no vemos nada y así no podemos ayudarte.

Comment: Añadiendo que estilos css estas aplicando se puede formular una respuesta mas concreta para tu caso.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema parecido. La solución que conseguí fue aprovechar bootstrap y crear la tabla con capas y **.col**, también tuve que agregar una clase (wide-mobile) con un ancho mínimo (`min-width: 1024px;`) para que mantuviera el efecto de tablas bootstrap en teléfonos

```html
<div class="table-responsive px-0">
    <div class="wide-mobile">
        <section id="thead" class="container-fluid">
            <article class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section id="tbody" class="container-fluid">
            <article class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col"></div>
                <div class="col"></div>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
@media (max-width: 800px){
    .wide-mobile{
        min-width: 1024px;
    }
}
```

Gracias a esto pude mejorar mucho la vista a nivel de css, espero te pueda servir

Answer (score 0):

Tu mismo lo dices, "En la parte superior puse `position:fixed`", haz las mismas restricciones css tanto para `thead` como para `tbody`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
} 

th,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

table.a {
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 180px;  
}

table.b {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 180px;  
}

table.c {
  table-layout: auto;
  width: 100%;  
}

table.d {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;  
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<h2>table-layout: auto; width: 180px:</h2>
<table class="a">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>table-layout: fixed; width: 180px:</h2>
<table class="b">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>table-layout: auto; width: 100%:</h2>
<table class="c">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<h2>table-layout: fixed; width: 100%:</h2>
<table class="d">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
```

---

En el siguiente enlace puedes ver todas las opciones basicas que puedes realizar.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp

---

En estos dos posts indagan un poco mas en el tema

https://css-tricks.com/fixing-tables-long-strings/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/table-layout/